# CSS Overide in Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So quick question, I just bought a template of a website that I really like, only for the about us page. I use a Volusion website, so we have a main CSS for the main template, and I want to be able to just have one page, the about us page, use this new css. If I put it in the body for the about-us page, it is obviously over ridden by the sites main css.

If it put it in the header with the rest of the css, it then throws off CSS all over the website, when I only wanted it reference to the about-us page.

Without having to go back, and rewrite every piece of CSS to make it unique only to the about-us page, so there is nothing conflicting, is there any quick method of having a unique set of CSS for just one page with a special jQuery call, or href. I don't want to use a ton of !important either.

Comment: You might want to include a CSS reset before your custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the About us in a id wrapper like this

```
<div id="about-us-wrapper" >
{...}
</div>
```

Then in the imported the CSS file, append

```
#about-us-wrapper .xxx
```

in front of each line.